# different arguments to bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

what is the usage of -ec in bash command on terminal

when I write

```
bash -ec
```

I get an error :

```
bash: -c: option requires an argument
```

Comment: Have you checked the manual page for -e and -c?

Comment: i did , it says -c is about opening a file , but could not understand it  @user1686

Comment: @ETL_Devs yes... don't you think you need to tell `bash` *which* file to open? Might that be the "argument" that is required for the `-c` flag?

Comment: I did this  "bash -ec | . test.sh r" where 'r' is an argument , script ran properly but still last line is same error "bash: -c: option requires an argument"

Comment: `bash -ec | . test.sh r` ? It looks like you are attempting to PIPE the results from bash into your script?  What is that pipe there for?  Also, if you use the shebang, you shouldn't even need to invoke it with bash directly.

Comment: "i did , it says -c is about opening a file , but could not understand it" – **What?** "[Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument …](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash)". Nothing about a file. This is an example: `bash -c 'date; echo foo'`.

Comment: From reading the above; consult `man bash`, more thoroughly this time.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski , thanks that one line helped